# What makes iOS more secure than other phone OS

Tags: malware, operating-systems, smartphone

Let's start off with an example. Here in Canada, credit card companies cannot upgrade you credit card limit. You need to make a request, that will then get analyzed and then, depending on your status as a payer, you might or might not get your limit increased. Why? Simply because the best security system here to prevent clients to spend all their money is to prevent them from accessing such funds.

Now in the SmartPhone world, Android is Open source and it allows you to run pretty much any APK you encounter. You can access the root and modify all that you want. This is a case where you can pretty much spend all the money you want and upgrade your limit.

It is a fact that there is more malware on Android than on iOS but is this layer of security preventing the malicious softwares?

Is the magic behind not getting much problems with malwares simply keeping users from doing *dangerous* stuff? Or is there something more to it.

Comment: This is a terrible analogy.  You can give yourself a message that your limit has been increased, but you can't convince anyone else that higher limit is real.  Relevant: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3448/2954

Comment: Apart from having a very difficult to understand question, your question (as I understand it) is very broad in that you do not reference direct examples of what you mean by 'more secure'.

Answer (score 1):

First, Apple's App Store is the most restrictive App Store. Unlike Google play where more phone-badware is found. Second, apps cannot access other apps, it's like a php open basedir restriction, each app is an island. Third, it's all about statistics, more people use Android than Apple-iOS devices. Fourth, Android is more open, anyone can find exploits in the code. iOS is locked down, mainly for people who can't handle advanced functions and settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing... I think you mean to ask 'why is iOS more protected from maleware than Android' If that is the case, you already touched on the answer. iOS is very locked down in terms of what a developer can access (and for our discussion, maliciously exploit). Android allows much greater access to more aspects of the OS and hardware thus making it much easier to exploit.

Another way to look at this is market share, iOS accounts for a very small amount of mobile devices whereas Android dominates nearly 3/4ths of the market. Therefore, it is more advantageous to the 'hacker' to develop maleware for Android OS's. [(reference)](http://www.idc.com/getdoc.jsp?containerId=prUS24257413)

You can view a graphic of the iOS layers and more documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/Introduction/Introduction.html